# dplyr r, removing all na values from dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

In R you can select all non-`NA` rows from a dataframe via:

```
set.seed(123)
nadf = data.frame(a = 1:20, b=sample(c("a","b",NA), 20, replace=TRUE))
nadf[complete.cases(nadf),]
```

The nice thing is that I do not need to specify which columns to check. R will check every value of every row and column if it is `NA`. I would now like to do this with `dplyr`.

In `dplyr` my first reaction would be to use the `filter` command. However, through `filter` I would need to specify every column that I want to filter on. Assuming that this dataframe has column names `a...z` and it would look something like this:

```
df = df %>% filter( a != NA, b != NA, ..., z != NA)
```

This is very verbose and I imagine there must be a better way to do this operation in dplyr. Is there?

Comment: You should provide some example dataset.  I don't think `df[!is.na(df),]` would give the intended results, when the number of `NA`s are different for each column.  But, you can get a vector out of `df[!is.na(df)]`

Comment: wow. ill refrain from writing questions without examples to check myself. my bad! made edit.

Comment: From the linked duplicate: "`na.omit()` takes 20x as much time as the other two solutions"